# Subject verb agreement confusion

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

"Fewer cavalry officers than infantry officers become Brigadiers but a higher proportion of Brigadiers from cavalry go on to **become/becomes** Generals."

"A large number of civil servants is/are corrupt."

I think in the first sentence 'becomes' is correct and in the second sentence 'are' is correct just because both sound right. But can somebody please explain the rule? In the first sentence the subject is **'a higher proportion** of officers' but the plural form of verb sounds right. Similarly in the second sentence, the subject is '**a large number** of civil servants' but again the plural form of verb sounds right.

Comment: The verbal idiom "go on" requires an infinitival clause as complement, not a finite (tensed) one, so agreement is not an issue in your first example. In your second example, "lot" is said to be 'number-transparent', so the number of the noun that is complement of the preposition "of" determines the number of the whole NP. In this case the plural NP "civil servants" thus requires the plural verb "are".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To become is an infinitive complement of "go on" and so must have the base form "become"

Comment: I agree with the comment, James. The verbal idiom "go on" requires an infinitival clause as complement, not a finite tensed one, so agreement is not an issue.